# Unable to cast object of type 'system.byte ' to type 'system.iconvertible in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

The Error says that Unable to cast object of type 'system.byte[] ' to type 'system.iconvertible. What should I do? Anyone....

```
            Dim ms1 As New MemoryStream
            Dim ms2 As New MemoryStream
            Dim data1 As Byte()
            Dim data2 As Byte()



            PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms1, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            PictureBox2.Image.Save(ms2, ImageFormat.Jpeg)

            data1 = ms1.ToArray()
            data2 = ms2.ToArray()


            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@signature", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = data2
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = data1

            Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Try
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Data Inserted!")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                    con.Close()

                End Try
```

Comment: Please don't tell us that an error is generated without telling us where. Sometimes it's obvious and sometimes it's less obvious and other times it's virtually impossible to tell where it is. If you tell us where then we don't have to waste time working that out first.

Comment: While it's not wrong, there's no point setting the `CommandType` to `Text` because that's the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are adding your parameters is wrong.  You're mixing up the use of `Add` and `AddWithValue`.  This:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@signature", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = data2
```

should be either this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@signature", data2)
```

or this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@signature", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = data2
```

Comment: Thanks sir! I think it work on my project. And sorry for not telling where the error is. Thanks a lot